# Can I monetize my R Shiny app using monetizer package?

Tags: r, shiny, r-package, shinyapps

I have an R Shiny app. I have deployed it at Shinyapp.io and I want it to show ads when the users use it. Can I do that using the monetizer R package? if not, is there other ways to show ads on Shiny apps and make money?

If yes, how am I going to do that? It is mentioned in [this instruction](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/03/the-monetizr-package-make-money-on-your-open-source-r-packages/) that it is possible to monetize packages by the monetizer. So I thought maybe I should organize my app as an R package at first. So, I did it. My question is after doing that, how can I use the monetizer package? If I've understood correctly, following the mentioned instruction, It can be done by creating a zzz.R file in the R directory of the package and placing the function `market_all(ad = "Have I mentioned my blog, Variance Explained?")` in it.
I did so but it didn't work. The app can't run after that. What is wrong with it? Should the zzz.R file be created in another way?

I appreciate any help everybody can provide and I also tag @David Robinson who has written the monetizer package. Hopefully, he can kindly help me with that.

To help you reproduce what I have now, I explain what exactly I did for organizing my app as an R package. I followed the workflow mentioned in [this chapter](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-packaging.html) of mastering Shiny book. I also use this book's example instead of a minimal example.

First I ran `usethis::use_description()`, which created a DESCRIPTION file. Next, I movedmonthFeedback.R, birthstone.R, app.R to the R directory and wrapped shinyApp() into a function. In the end, I can Re-run the app with `myApp()`.

> R/monthFeedback.R:

```
monthFeedbackUI <- function(id) {
  textOutput(NS(id, "feedback"))
}
monthFeedbackServer <- function(id, month) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(month))

  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$feedback <- renderText({
      if (month() == "October") {
        "You picked a great month!"
      } else {
        "Eh, you could do better."
      }
    })
  })
}
```

> R/birthstone.R:

```
birthstoneUI <- function(id) {
 p(
   "The birthstone for ", textOutput(NS(id, "month"), inline = TRUE),
   " is ", textOutput(NS(id, "stone"), inline = TRUE)
 )
}
birthstoneServer <- function(id, month) {
 stopifnot(is.reactive(month))

 moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
   stone <- reactive(stones$stone[stones$month == month()])
   output$month <- renderText(month())
   output$stone <- renderText(stone())
 })
}
```

> R/app.R:

```
library(shiny)

myApp <- function(...) {
  stones <- vroom::vroom("birthstones.csv")
  months <- c(
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  )
  
  ui <- navbarPage(
    "Sample app",
    tabPanel("Pick a month",
      selectInput("month", "What's your favourite month?", choices = months)
    ),
    tabPanel("Feedback", monthFeedbackUI("tab1")),
    tabPanel("Birthstone", birthstoneUI("tab2"))
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    monthFeedbackServer("tab1", reactive(input$month))
    birthstoneServer("tab2", reactive(input$month))
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server, ...)
}
```

Comment: ‘monetizr’ is a joke package. It does not actually do anything useful that you could harness to monetise a Shiny app. It’s a bit depressing that this was apparently not glaringly obvious from the package description.

Comment: What would you be willing to pay for monetizing help? ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph So is there other ways to show ads on the Shiny apps?

Comment: @MaryamMomeni Of course. Just like on any other website, you can insert a snippet that serves ads from an ad platform. Shiny is nothing special in this regard.

Comment: @I_O off course I'll be able to do that after monetizing. But I can not at the moment.

Comment: @KonradRudolph And can I submit the Shiny app to google like every other website so that it can be shown when a user searches it on Google?

Comment: @MaryamMomeni I am no SEO expert. But, again: Shiny websites are just regular websites (well, web apps anyway). So, yes, you can submit them to Google for indexing (and they will be indexed automatically if they are linked publicly). However, hosting services such as ShinyApps.io might have additional restrictions via `robots.txt` — In fact, [it appears that this is the case by default on ShinyApps.io](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-make-shiny-app-appear-on-search-engine/41292/4).

Comment: @KonradRudolph if I undrestood correctly, the problem is from deploying at shinyapp.io. Do other servers like RStudio Connect, AWS, etc. have a similar problem?